# apt-cyg can't connect to download mirror

Tags: windows, cygwin, apt

Each time apt-cyg tries to connect to its server, it just can't get response and gets stuck with connecting to it. Since I'm there via SSH, how do I change the download mirror without using graphical interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

The solution comes after using command option that is not disturbed on daily basis.

`$ apt-cyg --help`

```
apt-cyg: Installs and removes Cygwin packages.
  "apt-cyg install <package names>" to install packages
  "apt-cyg remove <package names>" to remove packages
  "apt-cyg update" to update setup.ini
  "apt-cyg show" to show installed packages
  "apt-cyg find <patterns>" to find packages matching patterns
  "apt-cyg search <patterns>" to find packages matching patterns (alias of find)
  "apt-cyg describe <patterns>" to describe packages matching patterns
  "apt-cyg packageof <commands or files>" to locate parent packages
Options:
  --mirror, -m <url> : set mirror
  --cache, -c <dir>  : set cache
  --file, -f <file>  : read package names from file
  --noupdate, -u     : don't update setup.ini from mirror
  --ignore-case, -i  : Ignore case distinctions in <patterns> when finding packages
  --help
  --version
```

As we can see, there's a `--mirror` option. And [here](https://cygwin.com/mirrors.html)'s a list of Cygwin mirrors.

Now we can do:

`apt-cyg --mirror "mirror site"`, replacing "mirror site" with a mirror link you've chosen.

Depending on where you get apt-cyg--or maybe on the version of it?--that --mirror option might work *without* double-dashes in front of it (and the help information displayed via `apt-cyg --help` may vary).